# Как правильно организовать инфраструктуру WebApi приложения?

Tags: c#, ооп, архитектура, asp.net-web-api

Возникла задача разработать простое приложение на ASP.NET WebApi 2.0 + EntityFramework + MSSQL.
Тут я хочу задать вопросы по серверной стороне приложения.
Опыта разработки программ почти нет. 
Основные обязанности приложения:

1) Сохранение сущностей в БД;

2) Редактирование сущностей;

3) Поиск сущностей по некоторым атрибутам.

Как я представляю себе картину:

Разделить сервер на 5 сборок (пакетов):

1) само API - контроллеры. Знает только о существование уровня представления данных. Основная задача получение данных из запросов + валидация этих данных.

2) Уровень логики представления. Описание вьюмодели (DTO). Тут происходит преобразование Entity в DTO и обратно. Знает только о существовании уровня служб и бизнес логики.

3) Уровень служб. Тут выполняются обращения к уровню доступа данных, уровню бизнес логики. Знает о существовании уровня доступа к данным и бизнес логики.

4) Уровень бизнес логики. Описание модели + бизнес логика. Не знает ни о ком кроме себя.

5) Уровень доступа к данным (DAL). Тут описываются процессы взаимодействия с БД. Не знает ни о ком кроме себя.

Дальше я не совсем понимаю как правильно установить взаимодействие между пакетами:

Случай создания сущности:

Как я понимаю контроллеры получают web request, достают из него какие-то данные (DTO) валидируют их и в случае корректного запроса обращаются к уровню логики представления данных. Далее там какой-то класс (EntityCreator) принимает DTO, конвертирует ее в бизнес сущность и обращается к уровню служб (EntityService). Служба получает сущность, открывает контекст взаимодействия с БД, при необходимости дозаполняет какие-то атрибуты, устанавливает необходимые связи (все это она делает взаимодействуя с бизнес логикой) и обращается к DAL с целью сохранения полученной сущности. DAL возвращает сохраненную сущность службе, служба возвращает сущность уровню представления данных (EntityCreator), далее она конвертируется в соответствующую DTO и контроллер отдает ответ.

Собственно вопрос в том корректно ли так организовывать взаимодействие модулей и их разбиение. Смущает то что уровень представления данных должен понимать к какой службе обращаться. Возможно это следует делать на уровне контроллеров API ? Тогда контроллер обращается к уровню представления что бы преобразовать DTO в сущноть, затем контроллер обращается к службе с полученной сущнотью, и опять обращается к уровню представления с результатом который ему вернула служба.